# Settings not sticking between tasks

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm trying to reduce my build script code by removing duplication. However, I can't find a way to make it work.

This is what I have today (but more repetition):

```
task testA(type: Test) {
    exclude 'folderA/*'
    environment 'MYVAR', 'myvar'
    ...
}
task testB(type: Test) {
    exclude 'folderA/*'
    environment 'MYVAR', 'myvar'
    ...
}
```

And I have tried to reduce the repetition by doing this:

```
task setupTest(type: Test) {
    exclude 'folderA/*'
    environment 'MYVAR', 'myvar'
}

task testA(type: Test) {
        ...
}
testA.dependsOn setupTest

task testB(type: Test) {
        ...
}
testB.dependsOn setupTest
```

The block setupTest runs before testA and testB, but the exclude and env variable are lost (tested with print statements).

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: A gradle file is just a groovy script, would it not be simpler to define a groovy function and invoke that normally instead of depending on call hooks on the gradle side?

Comment: I've tried that but did not get it to work either. Don't know how to access the environment and exclude functions or how to pass access to them.

Answer (score 0):

What about your custom Test Task ?

```
class MyTest extends Test {
    @TaskAction
    def init() {
        exclude 'folderA/*'
        environment 'MYVAR', 'myvar'
    }
}

task testA(type: MyTest) {
    // ...
}

task testB(type: MyTest) {
    // ...
}
```